# jQuery target element by its id attribute using the href attribute of another element?

Tags: jquery, css

When the user clicks on a `div.nav` element jQuery changes its class to `active`. Currently it sets `display: block` to all three of the `div.content` elements. I want jQuery to only set the `display: block` property on the `div.content` elements that have the `active` class. Here is my code:

```
$('div.nav').on('click', 'a:not(.active)', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
});

$("div.nav a").click(function(){
    $("div.content").css("display", "block");
});
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <a class="active" href="#1"></a>
    <a href="#2"></a>
    <a href="#3"></a>
</div>
<div id="1" class="content active"></div>
<div id="2" class="content"></div>
<div id="3" class="content"></div>
```

```css
.content {
    display: none;
}
.content.active {
    display: block;
}
```

What can I do here?

Comment: You don't really need js/jq for that behaviour, you could use CSS only. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/5xoh97uv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to add/remove the class from the corresponding `.content` elements, you can retrieve the `href` attribute of the clicked `a` element in order to form the selector to select the `.content` element. For instance:

[**Working Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/dkpLovrj/)

```
$('div.nav').on('click', 'a:not(.active)', function() {
  var selector = this.getAttribute('href');

  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(selector).addClass('active').siblings('.content').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
$("div.content").css("display", "block");
```

To this:

```
$("div.content.active").css("display", "block");
```

If I understand you correctly.  It will only target div elements which have both the content and the active classes.

Comment: `content.active` already has the style of `display: block`. OP needs to handle changing the active class on click of the menu item, based on the href.